# Modo Interactivo V/S Ide Python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Una pregunta; ¿Por qué si hago esto desde modo interactivo de ***python*** funciona y desde ***"spyder/ninja"*** no?.

**Python**

```
»> from numpy import *
»> a = array([10,20,30,40])
»> append(a,50)
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
»>
```

---

**Spyder y Ninja**

```
from numpy import *
a = array([10,20,30,40])
append(a,50)
print a
[10 20 30 40]
```

Answer (score 2):

En el modo interactivo te devuelve el resultado de la operación. Lo hace así porque es práctico (e interactivo). Si quieres conservar el resultado deberás guardarlo en una nueva variable. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
import numpy as np # from numpy import * es SIEMPRE una malísima idea
a = np.array([10,20,30,40])
b = np.append(a,50)
print(b)
```

Y ahora, el resultado será:

```
[10 20 30 40 50]
```

Otra cosa más, el uso de `numpy.append` suele ser muy costoso (en proceso y memoria) y suele haber mejores métodos de extender un *numpy.array*.

Answer (score 1):

El código no es el mismo en el primer caso como en el segundo caso. Te falta imprimir la variable `a` en la consola interactiva.

La función `append` permite añadir un elemento nuevo a una lista. Esta función, **crea una nueva lista y la devuelve**, y eso es lo que ocurre en el primer caso, después de llamar a la función, te devuelve una nueva lista. Ahora bien, la lista original almacenada en `a` no se ha alterado. Puedes comprobarlo imprimiéndola por pantalla:

```
>>> print a
[10 20 30 40]
```

Saludos.

Comment: Las listas son mutables, si usas el método `append` sobre una lista siempre modifica el objeto con el nuevo elemento añadido, aunque no lo guardes en una nueva variable. En este caso, está usando la función `numpy.append` sobre un *numpy.array*, que es un poco diferente a como funcionan las listas en Python.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, no conocía las diferencias.

Comment: Importar con `from whatever import *` hace que pasen estas cosas y haya nombres parecidos que no sabemos de donde salen ;-)

Comment: imprimí a y este fue el resultado
`>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array([10,20,30,40])
>>> append(a, 50)
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
>>> a
array([10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> `

esto quiere decir que no funciona la función append en numpy.array?

Comment: Ahora entiendo. ahora estoy usando este metodo 

#!/usr/bin/python 
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([1,3,4]) 
b = np.hstack ((a, [10])) 
print b

Answer (score 1):

La función `print()` internamente llama a la representación `str()` (o método `__str__()`) del objeto, mientras que el modo interactivo está utilizando la función `repr()` (o el método `__repr__()`). La primera ofrece una representación "human-friendly" del objeto, mientras que la segunda está más destinada al ordenador y en principio debería ser evaluable por el intérprete para recuperar el objeto original.

Si ejecutamos todo en modo interactivo:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [4]: print(a)
[10 20 30 40]

In [5]: str(a)
Out[5]: '[10 20 30 40]'

In [6]: a.__str__()
Out[6]: '[10 20 30 40]'

In [7]: repr(a)
Out[7]: 'array([10, 20, 30, 40])'

In [8]: a.__repr__()
Out[8]: 'array([10, 20, 30, 40])'
```

Aquí más información en inglés sobre [las diferencias entre `str()` y `repr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/554319).